# One link fails to open - of all Stack Exchange pages

Tags: support, safari, mac

Now, I'm aware this has been blocked by my ad-blocker, AdGuard, in Safari Mac, because of the error message…

```
Safari can’t open the page “https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/455474/rss-feed-interrogation-what-is-it”.      
The error is: “The URL was blocked by a content blocker” (WebKitErrorDomain:104)
```

Switching it off lets me access the page
…but this is one page of the thousands on Stack Exchange I've ever visited over the past decade & the only one it's ever blocked.

What's in this one page that is different to all the others?
Clickable link - [RSS Feed interrogation: What is it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/455474/rss-feed-interrogation-what-is-it)

The problem question is off-topic, so may not last long, & is not particularly important to me. I can access it on Chrome or on Safari by disabling the ad-blocker to interact with it.
I'm just puzzled why it should trigger my ad-blocker.

<strike>Now the problem question has been closed, the issue has gone away, leaving me no wiser, nor with any method to repro the issue.</strike>
Issue returned after just a few minutes.

Comment: What's interesting here is that there's no code to speak of and not even a single external link. I wonder if it's something else on the page, like maybe the title of a related question or the HNQ (not that I saw anything suspicious).

Comment: @Laurel - Presumably the HNQ would rotate randomly, thereby allowing me access *some times*. Just after the 'bad link' Q was closed, I briefly had access again, but for some unknown reason it has now decided I can't see it any longer. [I'm not unduly worried by this one-off issue, just puzzled.] I also don't have the web/coding skills to diagnose.

Comment: Did you try disabling filter lists in your ad blocker until you found the one that is triggering the issue? Please do so and let us know which one was causing the problem, then report the issue to the maintainers of that filter list.

Comment: This is off topic indeed since it's not about SE, but rather about the adblocker. You should ask this in their forums or support groups. (As far as we know, they might be blocking based on key words, e.g. if "cat" and "pink" appear in same page it's blocked. We can guess as much as we want, but we can never know for sure.)

Comment: Here we go again… It honestly is not worth my time to play divide & conquer through all combinations of ad-blocker. I asked here because familiarity with this site's structure may enable someone with better web chops than me to see what the difference was. Yet again a request for help on here is quickly turned into "Not my fault. Go away."

Comment: Well like I said, it's not about Stack Exchange. You can ask around in chat, people who also have the same blocker might have some tips, but as a question it's simply off topic. Nothing personal, just the site policy. (Questions not about SE are off topic)

Comment: It **is** about SE. It's precisely about SE. Why one single solitary page on SE would trigger something no other page ever has. How does that make it 'not about SE'?

Comment: Just a wild guess since [a similar issue on unrelated URLs was reported on AdGuard Github Issue](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardBrowserExtension/issues/466). If this is really caused by an overreaching filter, it might possibly be caused by "rss" or "feed" on the URL.

Comment: You may have better luck asking here: https://superuser.com/q/1758217/419485 https://serverfault.com/q/1118259/290545 - it's OT **here** because it's partly your end, which we can't see, whether it's partly our end or not. --- You can ***diff*** the pages yourself, if you are suggesting that is the answer.